# VBA Selenium can't find correct locator strategy

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I am trying to click on the "Exporter toutes les versions de chaque indisponibilité (.csv)" link on the following site:

https://www.edf.fr/groupe-edf/ambition-neutralite-co2-pour-edf-a-l-horizon-2050/optimisation-et-trading/listes-des-indisponibilites-et-des-messages/liste-des-indisponibilites

I have tried multiple things, but selenium can't find it to click it. I have tried multile things among them:

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div/form/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a").Click
bot.FindElementByCss("#zoneLinks > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a").Click
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id="zoneLinks"]/ul/li[1]/a").Click
```

Thank you for your help guys.

Best,
Eliot TABET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element in inside an `iframe`, You need to switch it first.

Use below css selector

```
bot.SwitchToFrame .FindElementByCss("iframe.iframe-responsive", timeout:=10000)

bot.FindElementByCss("li.csv:nth-of-type(1)> a").Click
```

[image]

Comment: How did you know this ? Where was it in the html tree ?

Comment: @J.Doe, See the attached snapshot.